# Unable to create Regex in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I have a regex to check `Max 70 alphanumeric characters and special characters: ' / \\ - ; @ and space` for which i am using the following regex pattern -

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9,.-\s'\\\/@]{0,70}$
```

*Please Note: testing this in https://regex101.com works perfectly fine*

And the following code to match it with string -

```
NSString *String = area@123\\
NSRegularExpression *regex  = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^[a-zA-Z0-9,.-\s'\\\/@]{0,70}$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSAssert(regex, @"Unable to create regular expression");
NSRange textRange   = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);
NSRange matchRange  = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:string options:NSMatchingReportProgress range:textRange];
```

Initially it was showing escape sequence error for which I changed the pattern to - `^[a-zA-Z0-9,.-\\s'\\\\//@]{0,70}$`

And now its resulting in crash  with message-

```
Assertion failure in +[UMValidations validateString:withPattern:]
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unable to create regular expression
```

Now what wrong is happening when this pattern works great on the regex tester.

Comment: Please provide the string literal with the regex you are using.

Comment: The problem most likely is due to the backslahes. There are several levels of escaping at work: Objective-C, regular expression and literal use. Therefore it's important you show how the expression appears in the code.

Comment: Just escape the dash or put it at the begining or at the end of the character class.

Comment: Hi. I have updated my code structure. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write regex patterns in Objective-C, the backslashes with special chars must be doubled. Besides, you need to also escape the hyphen (or place it at the start/end of the character class).

```
@"^[a-zA-Z0-9,.\\-\\s'\\\\/@]{0,70}$"
               ^^ ^^  ^^^^
```

You do not need to escape `/`. You need to use 4 backslashes to define a literal `\` because the regex engine uses a literal backslash (in an Objective-C string literal defined as `"\\"`) to escape special characters and to denote a literal `\`, the literal backslash in the Objective-C string literal must be doubled (`\\` in a literal string pattern (so, defined as `"\\\\"`) will match a literal `\` in the input). The main point is that the `\` in the string literal can form an escape sequence like `"\n"` (newline) or `"\r"` (carriage return), etc. So, there are two layers of escaping: one for the Objective-C engine, and the other - for the regex (ICU in this case) library.

See the [Objective-C demo](https://ideone.com/EyeCIW):

```
NSString *String = @"area@123\\";
NSRegularExpression *regex  = @"(?i)^[a-z0-9,.\\-\\s'\\\\/@]{0,70}$";
NSPredicate * Test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
if ([Test evaluateWithObject:String]) {
    NSLog (@"yes");
} else {
    NSLog (@"no");
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the mechanism behind this - You need to use 4 backslashes to define a literal \. Thanks

Comment: simply in C string literals `"\"` has spatial meaning. To provide this character in string literal you have to use `"\\"`. In regular expression  this character also has spatial meaning so you end up with `"\\\\"` just to match  single slash.

Comment: I added some more explanation with a small demo. Note that I removed `A-Z` just because the case insensitive modifier `(?i)` is used.